# Scala : Is there any operation in scala like rdd1.fun( val1) or rdd1.fun( rdd2)?

Tags: scala, operators

Suppose I have two RDDs: rdd1=(Double,Int,String), rdd2=(Double,String) and a function:fun1 wrote by myself and it would take both rdd1 and rdd2 as its inputs. how could I get the result like rdd1.fun1( val1) or rdd1.fun1( rdd2)?

For example,

        `rdd1=((1.53, 1, "22.35, 20.37, 15.52, 8.96"),
             (2.62, 2, "17.15, 1.83, 16.36, 5.24"), 
             (5.66, 3, "7.98, 14.16, 12.35, 6.36"))
        rdd2=( 1.53,"22.35, 20.37") 
             (ps. 1.53 is the minimal of[1.53,2.62,5.66]).`

And fun1 would return a new rdd3 from rdd1 where each element in rdd2 replaced each corresponding parameter in rdd1,the expected output is as follows,

```
    fun1(rdd1,rdd2)
    {
      ...

      new Tuple3(p1:Double, p2:Int, p3:String)
    }

       rdd3=((1.53, 1, "22.35, 20.37, 15.52, 8.96"),
            (1.53, 2, "22.35, 20.37, 16.36, 5.24"), 
            (1.53, 3, "22.35, 20.37,12.35,6.36")).
```

Maybe one way to call fun1 is rdd2.fun1(rdd1) or some other calling methods.

I'v tried "join", but it doesn't work for my problem, because "join" only return those pairs with the same key. 
But I don't know how to make fun1 work when rdd1 and rdd2 are the inputs.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: Probably you want `join` but it's difficult to tell. Please edit your question to include the details @YuvalItzchakov asked for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved my problem in the way of "map".   First, convert rdd2 to Array, then call the fun1 with Map, like this  rdd3 = rdd1.map( x = > myfun(x,arr(1))).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with implicit conversions or implicit classes.

```
implicit class RichRDD[T](rdd: RDD[T]) {

  def myFunction(other: RDD[T]): ? = { ... }

}
```

Here's an example with integers:

```
scala> implicit class RichInt(i: Int) {
     | def toThePowerOf(b: Int): Int = scala.math.pow(i, b).toInt 
}
defined class RichInt

scala> 2.toThePowerOf(4)
res1: Int = 16
```